# User principal name vs mail in Graph Users

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I am listing users from SharePoint into custom database table for use in custom application. While adding these users to custom database we need the user Id from Azure Active Directory (not user ID from SharePoint).

So based on email of user from SharePoint I search the user in Azure AD and get the ID.

For some users I see that Mail field from Graph User object is null but has User Principal Name field filled with email. And for other users has both Mail and User Principal Name filled.

What is the reason Mail field for users is null? Which field should I rely on as email value?

Thank you!

Comment: Hello is there anything else that I can help with?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***What is the reason Mail field for users is null?***

That value is for `Guest User` only. When you would add a `guest user` on your tenant there is a field with `Email address` which has shown below would treated as `mail` when you get user list using `Microsoft Graph API` then you would see that email value.

[image]

**`PostMan Test:`**

[image]

***Which field should I rely on as email value?***

You can rely on `userPrincipalName` which is `User name` on azure portal that is mandatory property. Once you set it that would be treated as `userPrincipalName` which you can be used for any scenario where you need tenant user email for example `user login on portal`

See the screenshot:

[image]

Hope that would help.

Comment: Glad to help you.

Comment: Do guests on Microsoft Teams have a `userPrincipalName`? And if so, is it the same as their email address?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, Not sure about teams but for graph API yes it does. Please refer to this [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/users?view=graph-rest-1.0#common-properties)

Answer (score 1):

`userPrincipalName` may not equal email, for example, "xxx_xxx.com#EXT#@xxx.xxx.com"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).